# Oracle select one to many returning duplicates from many JOINs

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning Oracle SQL and having issue with my current query. I am working with several VIEWs which some are one to many relationship.

I got the LISTAGG query to work and that is fine.

Now, I am adding a one to many VIEW_PHONE to my query.

I tried looking at PIVOT  but I get  kinda lost. I found this query using Max, Case and it works by itself. When I merge the Phone Case statements for

personal, business, and home phone number, the results have duplicates Skill strings.

Here is the outputs

Before Add VIEW_PHONE

```
1     John M. Doe  JDOE   1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4
```

After Adding VIEW_PHONE inner join

```
1      John M. Doe     JDOE     111-111-1111, 222-222-2222, 333-333-3333, 1;1, 1:1, 1:1, 2:2,2:2,2:2, 3:3,  3:3, 3:3, 4:4,4:4,4:4
```

I noticed that if I change the inner join clause PHONE.PHONE_TYPE('HOME', 'BUSINESS', 'CELL') to PHONE.PHONE_TYPE('HOME'), it will just give one skill string instead of 3. Since I am trying to fetch 3 phone numbers, it is affecting my join with the VIEW_SKILL.

How can I fix this query to not duplicate the skill string. Thanks..

```
SELECT PERSON.PERSON_ID, PERSON.FIRST_NAME, PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME, PERSON.LAST_NAME,    
       PERSON.USER_NAME,
       max(case when PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as HOME_PHONE,
       max(case when PHONE_TYP= 'BUSINESS' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as BUSINESS_PHONE,   
       max(case when PHONE_TYP= 'CELL' then PHONE_NUMBER end) as CELL_PHONE, 
       LISTAGG(case when SKILLS.SKILL_DESC = '1' then '1:1'
                    when SKILLS.SKILL_DESC = '2' then '2:2'
                    when SKILLS.SKILL_DESC = '3' then '3:3'
                    when SKILLS.SKILL_DESC = '4' then '4:4'
    when SKILL_DESC = 'ADMIN' AND PERSON.DEPT= 'DEPT1' then 'DEPT1:ADMIN' 
    when SKILL_DESC = 'ADMIN' AND PERSON.DEPT= 'DEPT2' then 'DEPT2:ADMIN'
                    else ''
                end, ',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC )  AS Speciality
FROM VIEW_PERSON PERSON INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID, PHONE_TYPE, PHONE_NUMBER FROM VIEW_PHONE
     ) PHONE
     ON PHONE.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID  AND PHONE.PHONE_TYPE('HOME', 'BUSINESS', 'CELL') LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID, SKILL_SHORT_DESC 
      FROM EPERSON.VIEW_UDRMS_PERSON_SKILL
     ) SKILLS 
     ON SKILLS.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID
GROUP BY PERSON.PERSON_ID, PERSON.FIRST_NAME, PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME, PERSON.LAST_NAME, PERSON.USER_NAME
```

Comment: Seems to be a follow on from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513561/oracle-select-query-for-one-to-many-relationship-between-two-tables/38516352#385163520).

Comment: Do the LISTAGG in the Derived Table before the join (instead of the DISTINCT) and similar for the MAX(CASE), too.

Answer (score 0):

You might do an *early aggregation*, i.e. aggregate before the join:

```
SELECT PERSON.PERSON_ID,
   PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
   PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME,
   PERSON.LAST_NAME,
   PERSON.USER_NAME,

   PHONE.HOME_PHONE,
   PHONE.BUSINESS_PHONE,   
   PHONE.CELL_PHONE, 

   SKILLS.Speciality

FROM VIEW_PERSON PERSON

INNER JOIN
 (
   SELECT PERSON_ID, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_TYPE = 'HOME' THEN PHONE_NUMBER end) AS HOME_PHONE,
      MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_TYP= 'BUSINESS' THEN PHONE_NUMBER end) AS BUSINESS_PHONE,   
      MAX(CASE WHEN PHONE_TYP= 'CELL' THEN PHONE_NUMBER end) AS CELL_PHONE
   FROM VIEW_PHONE
 ) PHONE
ON PHONE.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID

LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT PERSON_ID, 
       LISTAGG(CASE  
                 WHEN SKILL_DESC = '1' THEN '1:1'
                 WHEN SKILL_DESC = '2' THEN '2:2'
                 WHEN SKILL_DESC = '3' THEN '3:3'
                 WHEN SKILL_DESC = '4' THEN '4:4'
                 ELSE ''
               end, ',')  
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SKILL_SHORT_DESC )  AS Speciality
   FROM EPERSON.VIEW_UDRMS_PERSON_SKILL
   GROUP BY PERSON_ID
 ) SKILLS 
ON SKILLS.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID
```

This might be more efficient, too, because the number of rows is reduced before the join.

Comment: HI, I could not get this work in TOAD. I also have an 'AND PERSON.PERSON_DEPT = .....' inside the LISTAGG and TOAD says that PERSON is an invalid identifier even if it is defined in the FROM clause. I removed the PERSON.DEPT and TOAD still complains about the SELECT PERSON_ID after the LEFT JOIN saying Not a single-group group function

Comment: Well, the `SKILLS.` qualifier must be removed and a `GROUP BY` was missing, I'll fix my answer.  But when you need to access a column from `PERSON` you can't use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID,
  FIRST_NAME,
  MIDDLE_NAME,
  LAST_NAME,
  USER_NAME,
  home,
  business,
  cell,
  listagg(speciality,',') within GROUP(
ORDER BY 1) speciality
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT PERSON.PERSON_ID, PERSON.FIRST_NAME, PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME, PERSON.LAST_NAME,    
       PERSON.USER_NAME,phone_type,
      PHONE_NUMBER,
       case when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '1' then '1:1'
                    when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '2' then '2:2'
                    when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '3' then '3:3'
                    when SKILLS.SKILL_SHORT_DESC = '4' then '4:4'
    when SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ADMIN' AND PERSON.DEPT= 'DEPT1' then 'DEPT1:ADMIN' 
    when SKILL_SHORT_DESC = 'ADMIN' AND PERSON.DEPT= 'DEPT2' then 'DEPT2:ADMIN'
                    else ''
                end  AS Speciality
FROM VIEW_PERSON PERSON INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID, PHONE_TYPE, PHONE_NUMBER FROM VIEW_PHONE
     ) PHONE
     ON PHONE.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID  AND PHONE.PHONE_TYPE in ('HOME', 'BUSINESS', 'CELL') LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID, SKILL_SHORT_DESC 
      FROM VIEW_UDRMS_PERSON_SKILL
     ) SKILLS 
     ON SKILLS.PERSON_ID = PERSON.PERSON_ID
)
pivot ( MAX(phone_number) FOR(phone_type) IN ('HOME'
AS
  HOME,'BUSINESS'
AS
  BUSINESS, 'CELL'
AS
  CELL)) ) group by PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, USER_NAME, home, cell, business;
```

Gives:

```
1   guru            guru    111-111-1111    111-444-1111    111-333-1111    1:1,2:2,3:3
```

Uses 'PIVOT'.